# Magento 2 Error: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.catalog_category_flat_store_1' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, database

I started getting this error suddenly and I checked and the table does exist. I'm not sure how to start fixing this issue. I have attached a picture below:

[image]

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_e.catalog_category_flat_store_1' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, main_table.`name`, main_table.`path`, `main_table`.`is_active`, `main_table`.`is_anchor`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table`
>        LEFT JOIN `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite.entity_id = main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_autogenerated = 1 AND url_rewrite.store_id = 1 AND url_rewrite.entity_type = 'category' WHERE (main_table.is_active = 1) AND (main_table.path like '1/2/15/%') AND (`level` <= 3) ORDER BY `main_table`.`position` ASC

Comment: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` working fine?

Comment: @AnkitShah I'm actually getting this error when I try to run that command

Comment: Please run this Query in DB `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';` & after that run thi command
`php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`

Comment: @AnkitShah running the php bin/magento indexer:reset does the same thing and I already ran that command and then tried to run the reindex command and I get the same error

Comment: Have u tried above Queries & Command?

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/SQLSTATE-42S02-Base-table-or-view-not-found-1146/td-p/14182
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845822/magento-base-table-or-view-not-found
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59300/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-shopstel-magento-core

In Short You have to Create that Table Again. Install Default Magento & Copy/Paste that table

Comment: @AnkitShah But if you look at my posting then you can see that I took a screenshot showing that I do have that table. I saw other people had the same issue but they were also missing the table from their db and had to recreate it. I can show you the contents of my table if you want. Yes I also tried the above query and command

Comment: See also this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213277/no-such-entity-with-id-0-for-categoryrepository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue,you ***need to create flat table*** **`catalog_category_flat_store_1`**.

disable magento ***Catalog Flat for Category*** from `Admin>Stores>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog>StoreFront>Use Flat Catalog Category` make it **NO**

[image]

Then Flush magento Cache by `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Then you should **drop table** `catalog_category_flat_store_1`, if it is *exists in db*  by `drop table catalog_category_flat_store_1`

Next enable ***Catalog Flat for Category*** by `Use Flat Catalog Category` make it yes

Final,you need to indexing from magento cli : `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`